# Horizontal alignment of inlineImages in documents

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to insert an image inside a document file with the following snippet:

```
var style = {};
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
doc.insertImage(j, fileBlob).setAttributes(style);
```

The image is correctly inserted but it's always left aligned. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked with Documents before, so this is a bit of a guess. The insertImage call returns the InlineImage (not the doc), so you're applying the style to the image itself. Try wrapping the image in another element such as a ContainerElement and apply the centring to the wrapping 'container' element.

Comment: Yep that was the way to go, appended the image to a new paragraph. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try the modified code

```
var style = {};
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
doc.insertImage(j, blob).getParent().setAttributes(style);
```